# Receiving error message when trying to connect to GraphQL api over websocket using k6

Tags: websocket, graphql, hasura, k6

I'm going to perform a subscription test using k6 for the graphql api that uses Hasura. Here's what I've tried:

```
import ws from "k6/ws";
import { check } from "k6";

export const myFunc = (url, access_token, id, query) => {
  const headers = {
    Authorization: access_token,
  };

  const res = ws.connect(url, { headers }, function (socket) {
    socket.on("open", function open() {
      console.log(`VU ${__VU}: connected`);

      socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "connection_init",
          payload: headers,
        })
      );
      console.log("sending query");
      socket.send(
        JSON.stringify({
          type: "start",
          payload: {
            query: query,
            variables: {
              id,
            }
          },
        })
      );
    });
...

    socket.on("message", function (msg) {
      console.log(`VU ${__VU}: received message: ${msg}`);
      const message = JSON.parse(msg);
      if (message.type == "connection_ack")
        console.log("Connection Established with WebSocket");
      if (message.type == "data") console.log(`Message Received: ${message}`);
    });

...
};
```

And the logs with error:

```
INFO[0001] VU 1: connected                               source=console
INFO[0001] sending query                                 source=console
INFO[0001] VU 1: received message: {"type":"ka"}         source=console
INFO[0001] VU 1: received message: {"type":"connection_ack"}  source=console
INFO[0001] Connection Established with WebSocket         source=console
INFO[0001] VU 1: received message: {"type":"ka"}         source=console
INFO[0001] VU 1: received message: {"type":"connection_error","payload":"parsing ClientMessage failed: Error in $: When parsing the record StartMsg of type Hasura.GraphQL.Transport.WebSocket.Protocol.StartMsg the key id was not present."}  source=console
```

Why am I receiving the key id not present error? I have no idea what that means and couldn't find anything when I searched for it.

Comment: Have you debugged the values in the function? It seems the id field is not being passed in. Also, you haven't posted the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send a message over established websocket connection, the protocol dictates that you need to send `id` too. See this [link](https://github.com/apollographql/subscriptions-transport-ws/blob/master/PROTOCOL.md#gql_data).

Example payload:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "type":"start",
  "payload": {
    "variables":{},
    "query":"query MyQuery {\n  test {\n    id\n  }\n}\n"
  }
}
```

`id` can be any string decided by the client. When server send the response back, it will contain the same id. With `parsing ClientMessage failed` error message, Hasura is complaining that it cannot find the `id`.